# How to create 4d Array in Python

Tags: python

Assist me in creating 4d array. Below is my code for 3 dimension array. 
How do i get output in shape of (4,3,2,3)

```
Three_d_array - numpy.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
```

The above code provides output in shape of (3,2,3) but how to i get the 4d in this shape

Comment: please provide an example of the output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.arange(72)
a = np.reshape(a, (4,3,2,3))
```

or:

```
a = np.array([[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]], [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]], [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]], [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]])
```

or:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
a = np.repeat(a, 4, axis=0)
```

Comment: Hello, Can i code the same way as my 3d  instead of using arrange or reshape? Trying to visualize how to code would...be